# How does inner function access variable outside (in PHP)?

Tags: php

```
function f1($f2){
    function f3(){
        return $f2;    
    }
}
```

The key point of the question is that `f3` could *not* access `$f2` in PHP, and my goal is to use `$f2` in the inner `function f3`.

Comment: In Python, `return f2` would return `None` because it does not have access to `f2` as you claim it does. Not in Python2.7 or 3.4.

Comment: @Torxed [what do you mean](https://repl.it/BvOV/0) by "it does not have access"?

Comment: @Torxed nonsense. This code doesn't make sense, because f1 doesn't do anything with f3 so it is immediately thrown away, but if it returned f3 instead it would work fine. Indeed that's exactly how decorators work.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Just sad it doesn't have access to `f2`, never sad how or why. So no it's not nonsense, but I'm glad you clarified why.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO isn't a code-translation service.

Comment: I'm voting to re-open this question as on-topic, because it's a question about a language feature where another language is used for illustration.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correct, you want a closure, which is created explicitly with the keyword `use` in PHP. For example:

```
function f1($x){
    return function ($y) use ($x) {
        return $x + $y;
    };
}

$f2 = f1(7);
$f2(8) == 15;
```